# C++ libtcod example doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows

I'm starting to learn C++ (I have a very basic programming background) and I have in mind to create an old-school ASCII-looking roguelike. I know it may be easier in Python, but it **has** to be in C++. I'm using **Windows 10**.

I want some eye candy beyond basic ASCII, I've seen **libtcod 1.5.1** offers a lot of possibilities so I wanted to try it and follow [this tutorial](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Complete_roguelike_tutorial_using_C%2B%2B_and_libtcod_-_part_1:_setting_up). The problem is I'm stuck right at the beginning, because the libtcod demo "*samples_cpp.exe*" **works** but not the example code:

```
#include "libtcod.hpp"

int main()
{
   TCODConsole::initRoot(80, 50, "libtcod C++ tutorial", false);
   while ( !TCODConsole::isWindowClosed() )
   {
       TCODSystem::checkForEvent(TCOD_EVENT_KEY_PRESS, NULL, NULL);
       TCODConsole::root->clear();
       TCODConsole::root->putChar(40, 25, '@');
       TCODConsole::flush();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

If I launch the .exe compiled with the command:

```
g++ src/*.cpp -o tuto -Iinclude -Llib -ltcod-mingw -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -Wall
```

by double-click, it opens and closes a window very fast, and if I execute it from the console I get the in-console message:

```
24 bits font.
key color : 0 0 0
character for ascii code 255 is colored
```

Any clues of what I'm doing wrong? The project has all the proper .dll and include folder. This should be pretty easy :/

Thanks a million!

---

**UPDATE:**
Ok, I got some new info, gdb says this:

```
[New Thread 7468.0x1f24]
[New Thread 7468.0x203c]
[New Thread 7468.0x1bdc]
[New Thread 7468.0x190c]
[New Thread 7468.0x108c]
24 bits font.
key color : 0 0 0
character for ascii code 255 is colored
Using SDL renderer...

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x65e70d9f in TCODConsole::clear (this=0x1) at src/console.cpp:196
196     src/console.cpp: No such file or directory.
```

Not sure what that means, the console.cpp file of libtcode at line 196 has the following:

```
void TCODConsole::clear() {
    TCOD_console_clear(data);
}
```

Comment: The command you listed isn't for launching the generated .exe, it's for compiling the code.

Comment: I know, I mean I compiled the exe with that command. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Have you seen this thread? http://forums.roguetemple.com/index.php?topic=4239.0

Comment: I didn't! It seems to be the exact same problem, I'll see if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally managed to make it work. The problem was I didn't compile libtcod myself, I was using the files found in [this zip](https://bitbucket.org/libtcod/libtcod/downloads/libtcod-1.5.1-mingw32.zip).

It was pretty useful the information @Tyyppi_77 found in [this forum thread](http://forums.roguetemple.com/index.php?topic=4239.0):

> TCODConsole::clear method is located at line 196 in libtcod version
>   1.5.1, so the binary (.dll) library must be from 1.5.1 release. However, that release does not include MinGW libraries
>   (libtcod-mingw[-debug]). Yet gdb cannot find src/console.cpp file
>   implying you did not compile those libraries yourself. Which becomes
>   really confusing: where did you get your libtcod-mingw-debug.dll from?
>   Also, "this = 0x1" indicates  that TCODConsole::clear has recevied
>   totally wrong object pointer. Usually it happens when you call a
>   method on non-exising object (which should not be the case here) or
>   when linking against a library has gone haywire.
>
> I suggest you delete your current libtcod (and all traces of it) and
>   try to unpack a clean 1.5.2 release. If that will not help, try to
>   build the library as described here:
>   http://doryen.eptalys.net/data/libtcod/doc/1.5.2/html2/compile_libtcod_mingw.html [**NOTE: This link is broken**]
>   Note that you do not have to use the exact MinGW version mentioned on
>   that page. When you're compiling library yourself you are fine as long
>   as you're using the same version for everything.

In this [thread of github](https://github.com/tomassedovic/tcod-rs/issues/54) I got the idea of using Brogue's dll files, and they worked. But I suppose the best approach is to compile libtcod myself.